# Android: How to align view in LinearLayout to right?

Tags: android, css, android-layout

I have the following view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="1.5dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:foregroundGravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/separator_table_header_first" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**separator:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:endColor="#a9b5c2"
        android:startColor="#0076ff" />

</shape>
```

I tried to align border to right, but result is still on left (blue line) like on the image below:

[image]

How can I solve this please?

Comment: Add `android:gravity="left"` in `LinearLayout `

Answer (score 2):

Add the below line to your `LinearLayout` which would make your `view` to **right**

```
android:gravity="right"
```

Like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested this in my app. Its working as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    <!-- Change made here.-->
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="1.5dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:foregroundGravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/separator_table_header_first" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this programmatically in java**

```
View view = (View)findViewById(R.id.imgView);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:gravity` for `ViewGroup`. Here is the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:gravity):
Which your view, you can change like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="1.5dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/separator_table_header_first" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Or you can use `RelativeLayout` as parent view and `View` will :

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```